Is it possible to continue updating the page title in React even when the browser tab is switched?
I'm working on a Pomodoro application in React and I can't figure out how to continue updating the page title (<title></title>) when the browser tab is switched. Is this even possible with React? I know that browsers throttle JavaScript execution when the browser tab is switched but I was wondering if there is a work around for this? For example, the stopwatch on Google, regardless of if the tab is switched, the title continues to update.
What I mean by update is, the tab title in "Work mode" is: Work - 01:20 and when the timer is running and the tab is active, it continues to update with the elapsed time. If I switch tabs for 10 seconds, it stays as Work - 01:20 until I switch back to the tab, then it just jumps to Work - 01:30.
NOTE: This is not a traditional Pomodoro timer, "Work mode" is a stopwatch not a timer.
For my specific application, I am using React Helmet with a state value that gets updated every second with the elapsed time.

I guess this is because browser suddenly decides to pause tab's main thread. We cannot control this. But instead, we can use web workers and they will work at background. So, try to move your timer to web worker
